# Is there a way to trigger iPad sleep using gestures?

Tags: ipad

5-finger gestures allow you to do almost anything without pressing any of the 2 iPad buttons: except putting the iPad to sleep.

Anyone aware of a way to do this without pressing a button?

Answer (score 4):

You can enable the assistive touch panel. From this panel you can put the iPad to sleep with the touch screen.

To enable assistive touch:

1. Tap Settings
2. In Settings Submenu tap General
3. Scroll down the General submenu to find Accessibility.
4. Tap Accessibility.
5. In the Accessibility submenu tap AssistiveTouch
6. Trigger Assistive Touch into ON state

This menu (which can be minimized into every corner on your screen) allows you to do several actions using the touch screen, including sleeping the iOS device.